# Transportation in Netherlands: to and around Amsterdam

Tags: trains, public-transport, netherlands, amsterdam

In June, I plan to visit Amsterdam for 4 days.  We will need to travel to Hoofdorp and Bussum to visit relatives.  In the past I have stayed at hotels in the Hoofdorp area that provide parking as part of the lodging fee (i.e. not downtown), which worked out well with the rental car.

We would like to stay at hotel very close to the Centraal train station in Amsterdam, because I can walk to the attractions. It would seem that from parking stand point, [a 3 day continuous auto rental would not be cost effective and impractical (unless the local downtown rental company were to overnight parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135634/amsterdam-parking-a-rental-car-downtown/).

What are the travel options to rural areas like Hoofdorp and Bussum from Centraal Train Station?  I seek to understand and compare options with respect to time (primary) and financial (secondary) cost.

Answer (score 11):

It would depend on where exactly you need to be in those places. But if staying in a hotel near Amsterdam Central Station is a must, it would probably make sense to use **public transport**. The public transport planner for The Netherlands is called [9292](https://9292.nl/en).

There is a direct train to Hoofddorp, it's a 22 minute ride and costs € 5.30 per person, one way. And you may need a connecting bus, or ask your relatives to pick you up. However, if you're carrying a lot of luggage, this may still be a hassle.

To Naarden-Bussum station, it's basically the same story: A 26 minute train ride (or 29 to Bussum-Zuid), with possibly a bus. The train costs € 5.10 per person, one way.

If you're feeling adventurous, and weather permitting, you could rent a **bike**. Hoofddorp would be a little over an hour, Bussum an hour and a half. This would cost maybe € 15–20 per day for a 7-speed bike, or € 35–40 for an electric bike.

A **taxi** to either of these places would probably be around [€ 70–90](http://www.taxi-prijsberekenen.nl/). This might be more convenient than public transport and probably slightly faster, depending on the exact address.

Comment: I would use the 9292 site for door to door travel advice and the railways site ( https://www.ns.nl/en/journeyplanner#/ ) if you just want to know about trains.

Comment: @Willeke NS provides door-to-door planning too (requests are relayed to 9292), while 9292 uses train schedules provided by NS. In theory, they should give the same results.

Comment: In theory they do, in practice I prefer the one for the one job, the other for the other job as they work better.

Answer (score 1):

I second Berend for the options of public transport. Very convenient, reliable and not too expensive. If you do prefer to drive yourself and prefer to be flexible, you might find using a car sharing platform easy.

In downtown Amsterdam, you'll find [car2go](https://www.car2go.com/NL/en/#82523) for example. It's a bunch of cars to share which are parked throughout the city. These you can use to drive in and around Amsterdam. Bussum and Hoofddorp should work fine. Make sure you register upfront.

Please note: I've never used these myself (never had the need). I did see people using them a lot though.

Comment: At € 0.26 per minute this may turn out much to be more expensive than renting a car for a day.

Comment: Agree. But convenience of not having to search for a parking spot and picking up close by is worth something.

Answer (score 1):

From your wording it would seem that you are traveling together. In this case, the abovementioned €5.30 would result in €20+ if you are with two people in one day. That still leaves you at the train station of Hoofddorp or Bussum. Walking to the right location might easily take you 30-45 minutes. Therefore, I would in fact suggest to rent a car after all. It gives you a big amount of freedom and flexibility. Parking near the Amsterdam Central Station can be as cheap as €10/day (if you reserve): https://www.interparking.nl/en/find-parking/IJDock/